# how to select column dates for an between? "SQL"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these columns, I need to select dates from `2018/01/01` to `2018/07/07`. but all these columns need to be in this timeline.
Where am I going wrong in this select?

[image]

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: PLSQL, sorry for the tag

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this query? Can you show us an example of data and the expected result? Also, you really need to post this query as a text, so we'll be able to copy it.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause looks entirely wrong, but for once, you need to use `TO_DATE()` :

```
TRM.DUE_DAYS BETWEEN TO_DATE('2018/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd') AND TO_DATE('2018/07/07','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Comment: I put To_date, but this is saying "that the logical operator is not correct, that would be the" AND "OF" WHERE "

Comment: the where clause is wrong, why not columns of type date? it's because this is for auditing, I need to pick up dates that people did or recorded

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should explicitly convert the string to a date, rather than relying on implicit conversion. Your string in `yyyy-mm-dd` will fail for some people, depending on their `nls_date_format` parameter. You can convert a string  via `to_date()`, e.g. `to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`.

Secondly, condition in `WHERE` statement has to contain column name, operator (eg. `<`) and value, which we compare to. `BETWEEN` is also operator, which is then translated to two conditions: `<=` and `>=`.

So, just listing columns won't work, since it lacks operator and the value to compare with.

So, if you don't want to filter based on some columns, simply don't include it in `WHERE` clause.

Alternatively, if you want all these columns to be filtered with those days (**but names of columns suggest that they aren't dates..**), you could write:

```
WHERE (ACT.BANK_ACCOUNT_ID BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-07') AND
            (ACT.BANK_ACCOUNT_NAME BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-07') AND
            (BRA.STATE BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-07') AND
            (BRA.COUNTRY BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-07') AND
            (ACT.DESCRIPTION BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-07') AND
            (TRM.DUE_DAYS BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-07')
```

Comment: In this case I have to put a data logic directly, without the WHERE?

Comment: @JohnLeenda You just need `TRM.DUE_DATES BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-07'` in your where clause, nothing else :)

Comment: @Boneist Well, you right :) I've let myself copy and modify your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You generally can't stack columns in a WHERE clause. You need to spell out each condition. ie

```
WHERE 
ACT.BANK_ACCOUNT_ID between '2018-01-01' and '2018-07-07'
and
ACT.BANK_ACCOUNT_NAME between '2018-01-01' and '2018-07-07'
and
...
and
TRM.DUE_DAYS '2018-01-01' and '2018-07-07'
```

Comment: now I understand my mistake. I was doing a logic in the where but the logic of the comparison did not exist, and in this case it was not necessary since I want something fixed for all.